# How can I ACK A MESSAGE after doing analysis

Tags: python, multithreading, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ to get message from queue.

This messages being processed then sent to different queue in RabbitMQ.
here is how my program works:

- I have consuming Thread for message consuming that puts the revised message in local Queue..
- Another thread is listening and when a message arrives a nested Thread is created for analysis..
- when the analysis is done the message is sent to  RabbitMQ.
- I AM TRYING TO ACK after this operation is done but since consuming Thread works faster my channel is closed. How can I ACK after finishing my analysis?

Here is my Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle
from queue import Queue 
from threading import Thread
import time

class MyAnalysisThread (Thread):
   def __init__(self, comingQuery,deliverTag):
      Thread.__init__(self)
      self.comingQuery = comingQuery
      self.deliverTag = deliverTag
      
   def run(self):
      analysis(self.comingQuery,self.deliverTag)

def sendToRabbit(linkFeatures):
    
    .....send
              
      print(" [x] send to  rabbitMQ ")


def analysis(comingQuery,deliverTag):
    
           /////do analysis 
            

            sendToRabbit(message)
            global ResiveChannel;
            # I WANNA ACK HERE after analysis finish and sent 
            ResiveChannel.basic_ack(delivery_tag = deliverTag,multiple=False)

     
      

def analysisCall(messageQueue, consumerClose):
       print('//////////////////////////// analysis started')
       global sendChannel;
       sendChannel.queue_declare(queue='send')
       while True: 
        if(messageQueue.empty()==False):
            
            #get the message 
            message=messageQueue.get()
            comingQuery=message['comingQuery']
            deliverTag=message['deliverTag']
            messageQueue.task_done()
            
# each message will create different thread for analysis
            analysisThread = MyAnalysisThread (comingQuery, deliverTag)
            analysisThread.start()
            analysisThread.join()
            
            

            
        elif(consumerClose.empty()==False):
                # when the consumer is stopped go out the loop
                if(consumerClose.get()==True):
                    print('consumer stopped')
                    break;
        else:
            print('sleeping for .....1')
            # wait some n sec  before next iteration
            time.sleep(1)
            
       
        
   
def consumeFromRabbit(messageQueue, consumerClose):
    
    
    

    def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
   
        comingQuery=json.loads(body)
        
        message={'comingQuery':comingQuery,
                    'deliverTag':method.delivery_tag,
                    }
        messageQueue.put(message)
        
        
        
    global ResiveChannel;
    ResiveChannel.basic_consume(queue='link_raw', on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=False)

    print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
    try:
        ResiveChannel.start_consuming() 

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        consumerClose.put(True)
        print("consumer stopped")   
        pass
    
 

        
def main():
    print('this is main')
    
    #create shared ques for passing messages : 
    messageQueue = Queue()
    consumerClose=Queue()
    
    consumerThread = Thread(target = consumeFromRabbit, args =(messageQueue, consumerClose))
    analysisThreadCall = Thread(target = analysisCall, args =(messageQueue,consumerClose ))
    
    consumerThread.start()
    analysisThreadCall.start()
    
    consumerThread.join() 
    analysisThreadCall.join() 
    
    
    
    


if __name__ == '__main__':

    #create connection for sending 
    Sendconnection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('host',,'/',credentials))
    sendChannel= Sendconnection.channel()
    ResiveConnection = pika.BlockingConnection( pika.ConnectionParameters(''host',,'/','/',credentials))
    ResiveChannel = ResiveConnection.channel()
    

    
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Interrupted')


        try:
            sys.exit(0)
        except SystemExit:
            os._exit(0)
```

The error I got after few threads is :

> Exception in thread Thread-38:
> pika.exceptions.ChannelWrongStateError: Channel is closed.

Comment: I'm trying to make sense out of it, but I think your code has some structural issues (use of global variables, unnecessary use of threads in some cases) which makes it difficult to analyze.  You might find it easier to use some existing higher-level libraries for implementing producer-consumer patterns with a MQ backend.

Comment: i want to operate my work :

Comment: consuming then analyising thats why i used threads

Comment: [According to the pika developers](https://github.com/pika/pika/issues/963#issuecomment-366434699), as I suspected it is not safe to ack a message from a different thread from that which received it.  I think you will need to restructure your code.  It may be more scalable to have multiple worker processes that are consuming from the same queue.  Or, if you want to use a single process, you could do something like the example code in that GH thread of having a separate queue of messages to ack, and process that periodically from within your consume callback.